# OpenTK - GL. doesn't exist

Tags: c#, opentk, visual-studio-mac

Hi so I'm starting out with OpenTK and just following the tutorials on [this website](https://opentk.net/learn/) and I'm on [this tutorial](https://opentk.net/learn/chapter1/2-hello-triangle.html) and it says to write the code:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    GL.ClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

but when I try to write GL it doesn't come up in the instellisense and the output when I build it says: `/directory/that/the/file/is/in/Game.cs(13,13): Error CS0103: The name 'GL' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (OpenTKProject)`. I'm using all of the OpenTK namespaces but it doesn't work. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac version 8.7.4 (build 34) and MacOS 10.13.6 Heigh Sierra and I installed OpenTK and OpenTK.GLControl through NuGet with the warnings:

```
/Users/User/Projects/OpenGLProject/OpenGLProject/OpenGLProject.csproj: Warning NU1701: Package 'OpenTK 3.2.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. (NU1701) (OpenGLTK)
```

and

```
/Users/User/Projects/OpenTKProject/OpenTKProject/OpenTKProject.csproj: Warning NU1701: Package 'OpenTK.GLControl 3.1.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. (NU1701) (OpenGLTK)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are still gaps in which packages are fully realized/supported in the dotnet5 (a.k.a. .NetCore) and I also don't fully understand where to locate the comparison cheatsheet etc. I think .NET 4.8 or whatever was the last LTS Windows-only distro of .NET and in future they appear to be focusing a lot of cross-platform availability so it might take a while.

Other contributions by more seasoned .NET gurus may be able to shed some light on this.

Comment: OpenTK 4.0 has been released now, which supports .net core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration should have an object. It should look like this:

```
void OnLoad(EventArgs e, Object o)
{
//your code here
}
```

If that is not the problem, are you using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL? If not that will be your issue! Also ensure that you are using OpenTK.

```
//Insert this code into the top of the file :)
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
```